# AngularJS restangular post callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, callback, restangular

I am using restangular with AngularJS, and I need to use some function, which will trigger callback function/promise after POST response.
I tryed setResponseInterceptor which did not helped in this situation.
I need to use this function to lock form from submission until response will come back to client, and then unlock it to future use.
Do you know some magic for this?
I am using this code, and want to fire custom function when POST response will come to the client, something like .then()

```
    reportAPI.createReport = function (apiData) {
                return baseReport.customPOST(apiData, 'createreport');
    };
    var unlockForm = function () {
            console.log(new Date().getTime());

    };

    Restangular.setResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {

            if (operation === 'post') {

                console.log(new Date().getTime());

                console.log(operation);
                console.log(what);
                console.log(response);
                if (response.data) {
                    unlockForm();
                }
                return data;
            }
        });
```

Comment: setResponseInterceptor, but it is fired during app loading, and not called again after form submission

Comment: It'd be preferable if you could share your code and describe what the issue is.